# Reject all fonts from a directory except one with fontconfig

Tags: configuration, fontconfig

I'm trying to disable noto fonts for most other languages  except a few using fontconfig. It used `rejectfont` and `glob` element to disable all. Then used `acceptfont` element but couldn't activate it.

I've came across this message with similar problem in fontconfig mailing list which was never answered. https://lists.freedesktop.org/archives/fontconfig/2008-January/002826.html

What I have in my config file is here

```xml
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!DOCTYPE fontconfig SYSTEM "fonts.dtd">
<fontconfig>
  <selectfont>
    <rejectfont>
      <glob>/usr/share/fonts/truetype/noto/NotoSans*.ttf</glob>
      <glob>/usr/share/fonts/opentype/noto/NotoSans*.ttc</glob>
      <glob>/usr/share/fonts/opentype/noto/NotoSerif*.ttc</glob>
      <glob>/usr/share/fonts/truetype/noto/NotoSerif*.ttf</glob>
    </rejectfont>
  </selectfont>
  <selectfont>
    <acceptfont>
        <patelt name="family">
            <string>Noto Sans</string>
        </patelt>
    </acceptfont>
  </selectfont>
</fontconfig>
```

Is there an easy way like this other then writing a rejectfont rule for every family (which fontmanager uses).

Please, don't advice me to delete the fonts.

Answer (score 3):

Add the following XML to the file `~/.config/fontconfig/fonts.conf`, it will blacklist all the Noto language specific fonts:

```xml
<?xml version='1.0'?>
<!DOCTYPE fontconfig SYSTEM 'fonts.dtd'>
<selectfont>
    <rejectfont>
        <glob>/usr/share/fonts/truetype/noto/NotoKufi*</glob>
        <glob>/usr/share/fonts/truetype/noto/NotoNaskh*</glob>
        <glob>/usr/share/fonts/truetype/noto/NotoNastaliq*</glob>
        <glob>/usr/share/fonts/truetype/noto/NotoSans*</glob>
        <glob>/usr/share/fonts/truetype/noto/NotoSerif*</glob>
    </rejectfont>
    <acceptfont>
        <glob>/usr/share/fonts/truetype/noto/NotoSans-Regular.ttf</glob>
        <glob>/usr/share/fonts/truetype/noto/NotoSans-Bold.ttf</glob>
        <glob>/usr/share/fonts/truetype/noto/NotoSans-BoldItalic.ttf</glob>
        <glob>/usr/share/fonts/truetype/noto/NotoSans-Italic.ttf</glob>
        <glob>/usr/share/fonts/truetype/noto/NotoSerif-Regular.ttf</glob>
        <glob>/usr/share/fonts/truetype/noto/NotoSerif-Bold.ttf</glob>
        <glob>/usr/share/fonts/truetype/noto/NotoSerif-BoldItalic.ttf</glob>
        <glob>/usr/share/fonts/truetype/noto/NotoSerif-Italic.ttf</glob>
        <glob>/usr/share/fonts/noto/NotoSans-*</glob>
        <glob>/usr/share/fonts/noto/NotoSerif-*</glob>
    </acceptfont>
</selectfont>
```

and rebuild the font cache: `fc-cache -f -v`.

After this the amount of Noto fonts listed in Writer will go down from hundreds to 17.

Comment: Hi Roberto, that almost works. Turns out some Noto fonts are OpenType, so I had to replace "truetype" with an asterisk.